# Use of @ operator in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm quite puzzeled over some code I came over using a @-operator in Python. Do any of you know to interpret this use of @?

```
R = yn @ yn.conj().T 

for i in range(1, N-M): 
    yn = x_vect[M-1+i:i-1:-1]
    R = R + yn @ yn.conj().T

return R / N
```

Comment: It's [matrix multiplication operator](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/).

Comment: Recent versions of Python permit `@` to be used as a matrix multiplication operator. However, it's primarily intended for use by 3rd party libraries, since standard Python doesn't have a matrix type.